# On a subspace of $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Consider the subspace $S$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices given by $$S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} : a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{22} \in \Bbb R, \text{and } a_{21} = 0 \right\}$$
>
> 1. Exhibit a basis for this subspace, and prove that it is a basis.
> 2. What is the dimension of this space?

---

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am new in this material. I hope you can help me understand and solve this question. Thank you.

For additional information, I just don't know much about vector space. I know that subspace is a subset of vector space. And I don't know how to decide whether this is basis or not by looking at the given question as well as to decide its dimension. I am try to learn from the scratch but I got homework

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Think of $x (1,0,0) + z (0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you perhaps tell me which number (a,b) for that answer?

Comment: $$ a_{11} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + a_{12} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + a_{22} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$ Can you tell what the basis is?

Comment: Do you know what a subspace is, Nao? Do you know what a basis is? Do you know what "dimension" means? The more we understand your situation, the better we'll be able to help you. Please edit the body of your question to tell us what you know, and where you get stuck.

Comment: so that is the basis of that subspace, right ? how can I prove that it is basis, as far as I know,  basis consists of 2 conditions such as can be described by linear combinations and linearly. I am sorry I am asking a lot since I knew of this

Comment: @Nao You can use the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) to prove that the basis "vectors" (which are matrices) are orthogonal. Alternatively, you can stack the columns in a $4$-vector and use the standard inner product.

Comment: @GerryMyerson subspace is a subset of vector space and for dimension is the size of the matrices, right? Well, I don t know much about this so I am struggling to decide the correct answer

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo can you please tell me more about this?

Comment: No, a subspace is **not** just a subset of a vector space, and the dimension of a space is **not** the size of a matrix, so it's no wonder you are having difficulty with this problem – you don't know what any of the words mean! Instead of asking this question, you should be reading whatever study materials you have to learn what these words mean. Then you might be able to solve the problem, or at least to understand it.

Comment: @Nao Look at the three "basis matrices" above. Can you build any of them as a linear combination of the other two?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your advice, yes, I should study more then come back again to this question. I try to dig deeper for this material

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you very much for the help, I will look for this material again and come back